# Xubuntu - opening files with Enter

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar-custom-actions

I don't understand why if I select a file either in thunar or in the desktop and press Enter, nothing happens! I'd like to make them files be opened. How can I do it?

Comment: I have Xubuntu 14.04 and in Thunar I can press Enter or Ctrl O to open a file. On the Desktop, only Enter works not Ctrl O. I believe this is default for it to work the way I mention. Not sure why it does not work for yours.

Comment: I am using Thunar 1.6.10 on Xfce 4.12.